# How to assign x-axis and y-axis using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I am trying to graph a chart using VBA, I have 2 ranges rn1=Range("A1:A5") and rn2=Range ("B1:B5")

How can I set rn1 as x axis, and rn2 as y axis?
And vice a versa, rn1 as y axis and rn2 as x axis?

I know by setting range ("A1:B5") it plots them both on the same axis?

```
Dim rn2 As Range 

Set rn1 = Range("A1:A15") 
Set rn2 = Range("G1:G15") 

Set ch = Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes.AddChart2(Width:=300, Height:=400, _ Left:=Range("k5").Left, Top:=Range("k5").Top).Chart 

With ch .SetSourceData Source:=Range(rn1, rn2), PlotBy:=xlColumns .ChartType _ = xlXYScatter End With
```

Comment: my question is not too bright but I am just a beginner  lol

Comment: Dim rn1 As Range
Dim rn2 As Range

Set rn1 = Range("A1:A15")
Set rn2 = Range("G1:G15")

Set ch = Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes.AddChart2(Width:=300, Height:=400, Left:=Range("k5").Left, Top:=Range("k5").Top).Chart

With ch
    
    .SetSourceData Source:=Range(rn1, rn2), PlotBy:=xlColumns
    .ChartType = xlXYScatter 
    End With

Comment: *edit your question* if you want to add code - code in a comment is not easily readable...

Comment: Are the ranges `A1:A5 and B1:B5` or `A1:A15 and G1:G15` ?

Comment: Thx for replying, they are A1:A15 and G1:G15.